# Do "atomic" and "nonatomic" attributes on properties have any effect if you use a custom getter/setter?

Tags: objective-c

If I have a property declared in a class:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (atomic) NSString *myString;
@end
```

And I implement custom getter and setter methods:

```
@implementation MyClass

- (NSString *)myString
{
    // return something
}

- (void)setMyString
{
    // do something
}

@end
```

Does the "atomic" attribute on the property declaration actually do anything? Or is it only used if an automatic getter/setter is actually created by the compiler?

Assuming the "atomic" and "nonatomic" keywords don't do anything for properties with custom getters and setters, is there any convention for what attribute we should use for those properties?

Comment: If you're not going to implement atomicity, then the "convention" is to make the property `nonatomic` so clients know what they're dealing with.

Comment: "atomic" has the affect of giving you a warning when you use your own getter or setter, but not both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the `atomic` attribute on the property declaration actually do anything? Or is it only used if an automatic getter/setter is actually created by the compiler?

`atomic` is used only when a getter/setter is synthesized by the compiler. It is also [used to check the consistency of accessors for `readwrite` properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html):

> Because the internal implementation and synchronization of atomic accessor methods is private, it’s not possible to combine a synthesized accessor with an accessor method that you implement yourself. You’ll get a compiler warning if you try, for example, to provide a custom setter for an atomic, readwrite property but leave the compiler to synthesize the getter.

> is there any convention for what attribute we should use for those properties?

Apple does not require you to follow any convention, but you could use `atomic` and `nonatomic` attributes to document your own code. This would let readers of your code learn about the behavior of your accessors without looking into their implementation.